# Does this sentence even have a past perfect?

Tags: tense

"I am told to attend the meeting" 
Does this sentence even have a past perfect form? Is the past perfect form like this : They had asked me to attend the meeting?

Comment: I had been told to attend the meeting.

Answer (score 1):

They had asked me to attend the meeting. It's the past perfect. I had been told to attend the meeting. It's also the past perfect, but it's the past perfect of the 
sentence "I am told to attend the meeting".